# How to decouple JHipster frontend from backend

Tags: angularjs, tomcat, jhipster

I'm trying to figure out, what needs to be done in order to have the HTML/JS on my webspace (HTTPS and CDN) and the backend on my application server (TOMCAT). I can't find a global variable to do this, do I really need to change all AngularJS factories?

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: what are you trying to do, do you want to run a backend with your own client?

Comment: I want to run the javascript code on my webspace (domain1.com) and the backend on my application server (domain2.com).